# How to present an email box to a client in asp.net before sending the email

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2005, mailmessage

I just want to be able to pre-populate a `MailMessage` object with all the properties of the email (from, to, subject, body, and an attachment file) and present it to the web client to decide whether to send it **as is**, or edit the email further before hitting send.

Is there a way to do this in C# using asp.net (.net 2) via Visual Studio 2005?

Thank you

Comment: Yes. Its possible. Just create a page or dialog box and show the relevant properties before you send it.

Comment: Forgot to mention, that I am after a dialog box from the email client (Outlook 2007 preferrably). Yes, I know I can create a form to contain everything, but trying to avoid the obvious as surely these tools are there to be used. Why re-invent the wheel!?

Comment: Is this the dialog box launched after clicking on a `mailto:johndoe@example.com`link? You have no control over that, because that's happening on the client's machine and is totally separate from the web browser. It's actually being sent by Outlook. If you want control over the email, you need to use a [MailMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.aspx) and send it yourself using the [SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. In this manner, you have complete control over all aspects of the email

Comment: @mason You should say that as an answer, because that was the answer I had to swallow. You're right. There is no way of controling it which I found out the hard way. I did what you suggested and simply pushed the email out anyway, but CCing it to our client. That's the bext we can do. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a page (or a dialog box, I prefer using jQuery UI but I'm going to do this example as a page cuz I'm lazy)

```
To: <asp:TextBox runat="server id="To_TB /><br />
Subject: <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="Subject_TB" /><br />
Body:<br />
<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="Body_TB" TextMode="Multiline" /
<br />
<asp:Button runat="server" id="Submit_BTN" Text="Send Email" OnClick="Submit_BTN_Click" />
```

Codebehind...

```
protected void Submit_BTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MailMessage msg=new MailMessage("myserver@mysite.com", To_TB.Text, Subject_TB.Text, Body_TB.Text);
    SmtpClient client=new SmtpClient("myemailserver@mydomain.com");
    client.Send(msg);
}
```

It can obviously me much fancier, HTML emails and MailAddress instead of strings and all that jazz. But this should get you started. You'll have full control over it, unlike depending on the user having an email client.